# Google maps: change from map view to satellite view

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, satellite

I have a google map with javascript and i want after zoom in 100%,(full zoom) change the mode map from map view to satellite view, how done it in following javascript code?

**DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/keL4L2h0/

```js
//////// Loading Google Map //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $(function() {
            var latitude = $('input[name="latitude"]').val();
            var longitude = $('input[name="longitude"]').val();
            var lat = (latitude ? latitude : 38.341656192795924),
                lng = (longitude ? longitude : -122.68604278564453),
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';
            //zoomControl: true;
            //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE;

            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: (latitude ? 16 : 7),
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
                },
                mapTypeControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                overviewMapControl: true,
                rotateControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
                types: ["geocode"]
            });

            autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(event) {
                infowindow.close();
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(17);
                }

                moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
                $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
                $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
                $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
                $("#searchTextField").val('');
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
                $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
                infowindow.close();
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({
                    "latLng": event.latLng
                }, function(results, status) {
                    console.log(results, status);
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(results);
                        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                            placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                        moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                        $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    }
                });
            });

            function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
                marker.setIcon(image);
                marker.setPosition(latlng);
                infowindow.setContent(placeName);
                //map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( lat,lng ) );
                //infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px;width: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the current zoom level is greater than or equal to the maximum zoom level of the [ROADMAP](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId) MapType, change the mapType to SATELLITE:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    var maptype = map.getMapTypeId();
    if (map.getZoom() >= map.mapTypes[maptype].maxZoom) {
        if (map.getMapTypeId() != google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID) {
            map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID)
            map.setTilt(0); // disable 45 degree imagery
        }
    }
});;
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t6m1seb8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
//////// Loading Google Map //////////////////
$(function() {
  var latitude = $('input[name="latitude"]').val();
  var longitude = $('input[name="longitude"]').val();
  var lat = (latitude ? latitude : 38.341656192795924),
    lng = (longitude ? longitude : -122.68604278564453),
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: (latitude ? 16 : 7),
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    },
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    rotateControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    map.setZoom(20);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var maptypes = map.mapTypes;
    var maptype = map.getMapTypeId();
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "[" + maptype + "] zoom: " + map.getZoom();
    if (map.getZoom() >= map.mapTypes[maptype].maxZoom) {
      if (map.getMapTypeId() != google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID) {
        map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID)
        map.setTilt(0); // disable 45 degree imagery
      }
    }
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
    marker.setIcon(image);
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
    infowindow.setContent(placeName);
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```