# Google maps does not zoom in past a certain point

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is the project

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
scrollwheel: false,
navigationControl: false,
mapTypeControl: false,
scaleControl: false,
draggable: false,
zoom: 15,

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.239415, -118.529339),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yxg7spbp/2/

the problem is i want to zoom in closer to see the buildings outlines of the campus however if i change the zoom value past 15 it does not have any effect, how can i zoom in closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terrain map type is limited to a zoom of 15.  If you want to zoom in more, use the ROADMAP map type (up to about 19) or SATELLITE map type (use the [MaxZoom Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom) to determine the maximum zoom available)

related question: [Google maps: change from map view to satellite view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582771/google-maps-change-from-map-view-to-satellite-view)

[fiddle that changes the mapType when the current type reaches its maxZoom](https://jsfiddle.net/yxg7spbp/4/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    var maptype = map.getMapTypeId();
    if (map.getZoom() >= map.mapTypes[maptype].maxZoom) {
        if (map.getMapTypeId() == google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN) {
            map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
        } else if (map.getMapTypeId() != google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID) {
            map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID)
            map.setTilt(0); // disable 45 degree imagery
        }
    }
});;
```

> The Google Maps API provides map tiles at various zoom levels for map type imagery. Most roadmap imagery is available from zoom levels 0 to 18, for example. Satellite imagery varies more widely as this imagery is not generated, but directly photographed.